# how can do i add time delay without using the time.sleep() command?

Tags: python

from time import time

```
start_time = time()
end_time = start_time + 3
next_z = start_time + 0.5
while next_z < end_time:
    if time() > next_z:
        print('z')
        next_z += 0
```

Is it correct or i need to change anything?

Comment: `next_z += 0` looks strange

Comment: yeah its is next_z += 0.5

Answer (score 1):

```
from threading import Event
seconds = 5
Event().wait(seconds)
```

I imported the Event class which create events that can be listened to by other threads. I then called the wait method which blocks the event it's run on, here I run it on the main thread, which is blocked.

**Check this article for more:**

[https://stackabuse.com/python-make-time-delay-sleep-for-code-execution/#:~:text=20%3A29%3A19.182505-,Delaying%20Code%20with%20Event,-The%20Event%20class](https://stackabuse.com/python-make-time-delay-sleep-for-code-execution/#:%7E:text=20%3A29%3A19.182505-,Delaying%20Code%20with%20Event,-The%20Event%20class)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in running your script with a delay, you can use code below:

```py
from time import time
end_time = time() + 3
print("delay starts")
while True:
  now = time()
  if now > end_time:
    print("deley with 3s at " + str(now))
    end_time = now + 3
```

This code will result in an output like what follows:

```
delay starts
deley with 3s at 1645388659.1063917
deley with 3s at 1645388662.106392
deley with 3s at 1645388665.1063921
deley with 3s at 1645388668.1063924
deley with 3s at 1645388671.1063926
deley with 3s at 1645388674.1063929
deley with 3s at 1645388677.106393
deley with 3s at 1645388680.1063933
deley with 3s at 1645388683.1063936
deley with 3s at 1645388686.1063938
deley with 3s at 1645388689.106394
deley with 3s at 1645388692.1063943
```